# Add scatter points on top of ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

After calling `ggsurvplot(...)` I want to superimpose some points from another data frame `df` containing two columns `time` and `survival`. I'm looking for tips on accomplishing this.

Edit: some code as an example

```
require("survival")
require("survminer")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

# Basic survival curves
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)

# Example points
x <- fit$time
y <- fit$n.risk
```

How would I superimpose `points(x, y)` on ggsurvplot plot.

Comment: please provide an example of data (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: sometimes having the 2 plots side by side, and not superimposed would be the correct thing to do in a graphic perspective. but some code or data would be easier to help create what you are wanting. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ggplot`-type object is part of the object returned by `ggsurvplot()` and can be addressed as `$plot`:

```
ggplot1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)$plot
```

You can work with it as with a usual `ggplot` object and add other layers. For your specific example, however, it is not clear how you want to define `Y` coordinate of your points: `fit$n.risk` is a number between 1 and 138 while your plot is in 0..1 range. Here is one option:

```
ggplot1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)$plot
df1 <- data.frame(time=fit$time, nRisk=fit$n.risk, nRiskRel=fit$n.risk/max(fit$n.risk))  
ggplot1 + geom_point(aes(x=time, y=nRiskRel), data = df1, alpha=0.5, size=3)
```

[image: example plot]

You may want to add colors etc.